# SQL If records are repetitive select the one with the max id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns older versions of some records (due to bad database design) and i try to get only the newest ones. So i try to get the ones with Max Id's but query is complicated and there are lots of records. So subselect queries like this wont work:

```
SELECT row 
FROM table 
WHERE id=(
    SELECT max(id) FROM table
    )
```

And here's my query. By the way my company is using Testlink, if you're familiar with it and you have a better solution for this, it would be appreciated.

```
SELECT req_doc_id, scope,nh.parent_id,nh.id
FROM (SELECT nh.id, req_doc_id,doc_id FROM nodes_hierarchy nh,
req_specs r1, requirements r2 
WHERE nh.parent_id = r1.id AND nh.id = r2.id 
AND (r1.doc_id LIKE '%BlaBla%' OR r1.doc_id LIKE '%Tralala%')) 
AS t1, nodes_hierarchy nh, req_versions r1 
WHERE t1.id = nh.parent_id AND nh.id = r1.id
```

And resultset is

```
 NAME..................ID              
____

BlaBla1..............163        

BlaBla1..............190

BlaBla2..............173

Tralala..............15

Tralala2.............26

Tralala2.............19
```

What I want is:

```
 NAME..................ID              
____


BlaBla1..............190

BlaBla2..............173

Tralala..............15

Tralala2.............26
```

Comment: Can we double check which RDBMS you're using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
 SELECT Name,Notes
 FROM (select nh.id ,req_doc_id as Name, scope as Notes  from 
 (select nh.id,req_doc_id,doc_id  from nodes_hierarchy nh ,
 req_specs r1, requirements r2 
 where nh.parent_id = r1.id  and nh.id = r2.id 
 and ( r1.doc_id like '%Tralala%'
 or r1.doc_id like '%BlaBla' ) )    

 as t1,
 nodes_hierarchy nh, req_versions r1 
 where t1.id = nh.parent_id  and nh.id = r1.id ) AS TABLO
 INNER JOIN(
 SELECT MAX(nh.id) ID ,scope FROM  (select nh.id,req_doc_id,doc_id  from nodes_hierarchy nh ,
 req_specs r1, requirements r2 
 where nh.parent_id = r1.id  and nh.id = r2.id 
 and (r1.doc_id like '%Tralala%'
 or r1.doc_id like '%BlaBla' ) )  

 as t1, nodes_hierarchy nh, req_versions r1 where t1.id = nh.parent_id  and nh.id = r1.id GROUP BY req_doc_id)
 INNERTABLE on INNERTABLE.ID = TABLO.ID;
```

Comment: I just don't think we should be advocating arcane join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TB.NAME,TB.ID FROM TABLE TB
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT NAME,MAX(ID) ID FROM TABLE GROUP BY NAME
)INNERTABLE ON INNERTABLE.ID=TB.ID
```

Try above query.

Comment: As i said subselect queries will slow a lot due to number of records and the query has already have lots of complexity

Comment: @LabadaEfel2 it's not subset query.And it is the only optimize way..!!

Comment: But look at my query man :) wont it cost a lot with Inner Join?

Comment: It is a subquery. But that's not to say that it isn't efficient.

Comment: "A lot of Inner Join ?" No It won't! That's not how SQL work! There is only one Inner Join so it won't Cost more than one Inner Join. But if you are speaking about a lot of query. No it won't. It will query the Max(ID) for each name and tell the other query: "Those are the Id you are looking for". If you are still afraid of the Cost of such thing well if a GroupBy and a Max is a big request please update your server.

Comment: In fact in `SELECT NAME,MAX(ID) ID ` the `NAME`is useless but won't hurt performance.

Comment: You should try things before dismissing their performance characteristics. With correct indexing both the sub query and the job can be extremely quick.